# how to pass JSON with Array,String

Tags: apex, json, apex-webservice

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v/restAPIKeyGeneration/*')

global with sharing class APIforKeyGeneration{

    global class Account{
       public String sname;
       public String bp;

   }

    @HttpPost
    global static String CallTo(Account[] account,String sourceSystemID){
        system.debug('sourceSystemID');
        system.debug('rtrtr');
        return 'key' ;
    }
}
```

Guys, please help me,how to test this in postman,I used below to pass array but I also have to pass String

```
{
    "account": [{
        "sName": "REST Account"

    }, {
        "sName": "REST Account"

    }]
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you update your existing question instead of creating another question.

Comment: no.i want to know,how can i pass string along with that array

Comment: have you check on JSON Generator https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needs to be part of the JSON object.

```
{
    "account": [{
        "sName": "REST Account"

    }, {
        "sName": "REST Account"

    }],
    "sourceSystemID": "12345"
}
```

The key name should match the parameter name, and the value must be compatible with the destination data type (e.g. a Decimal expects an unquoted number, while a String requires quotes).

You may want to learn more about the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that sName is the standard name Account field but it is incorrect no need use the API name of the field, in this case is "Name":

Can you try this?

```
{
    "account": [{
        "Name": "REST Account"

    }, {
        "Name": "REST Account"

    }],
    "sourceSystemID": "12345"
}
```